# TypeError using xml.etree.ElmentTree

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to test attributes from an xml file against some numbers. When I run `type()` on the attributes (in this case `currentNote`):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('booze.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for note in root.iter("note"):
    currentNote = note.get("default-x")
    print type(currentNote)
```

The type prints as `<type = 'str'>`

However, if I change the last line to this:

```
print type(int(currentNote))
```

I get this:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Not sure what's going on - it seems like I'm misunderstanding what the etree parser is returning...

Answer (score 0):

```
currentNote = note.get("default-x")
```

`get` returns `None` by default if there is no match for the key.

You cannot make an `integer` from a `NoneType`.

```
In [51]: int(None)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-3f3b1d3c7325> in <module>()
----> 1 int(None)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

You should print `note` in your loop to confirm the data is how you expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks, but that's returning a <type 'str'> as well.
Yikes - except the first one! Thanks. I'll just try: that away.

Comment: I don't mean type, I mean exactly what the values are. `print note` `print note.get("default-x")`, in your loop.

Comment: Ahh. I see. I got it - the first one was still the culprit. Thanks.